# THREEJS: How to render different models in seperate DIVs?

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering, render

*(I'm new to Three.js)*

---

### Description

I'm working on a 3D Viewer for multiple stl models. Every model should get rendered in a seperate div, so you'll get a grid with different models. 
The filenames are stored into a json file. With a for loop I loop through the json and store the filename in "var filename". I use that variable to complete the path to the model.

---

### Details

```
var filename = data[i].Filename;
```

With a for loop I am able to get all the filenames out of the json file.

```
loader.load('model/' + filename, function(geometry) {...
```

I then add filename to complete the model path.

```
modelContainer = document.createElement('div');
modelContainer.className = modelClass;
document.getElementById(modelId).appendChild(modelContainer);
```

A div with a classname gets created inside the div with the given ID. And the model should get rendered into a canvas inside the div (the div with the class).

---

### THE PROBLEM

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPUXT.png)
What happens now is that the code puts all the models (3 models in this example) into the last div. The first two divs that were meant for model 1 and 2 are black.

After lots of experimenting and analysing I couldn't find the solution yet. *Maybe it could be that I have to store all the scenes in an array, and loop all the scenes in the render function?*

---

### Complete Html and Javascript

You can find the full project code (without the .stl models) here:
https://codepen.io/indoguy/project/editor/XqNKGQ

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="modelGrid">
        <!-- The models will be uploaded within this grid -->
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/three.js"></script>
<script src="js/STLLoader.js"></script>
<script src="js/WebGL.js"></script>

<script>
    var modelDiv = document.getElementById('modelGrid');
    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // In this code snippit I will read the model filenames out of the json.
    // Add URL where the json is stored
    ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8888/3D%20Modeling/3D%20Previewer/3D%20Previewer%20Library/models.json');
    ourRequest.onload = function() {
        var queueData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
        renderHTML(queueData);
    };
    ourRequest.send();

    function renderHTML(data) {
        // 3D Model Process
        if (WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable() === false) {
            document.body.appendChild(WEBGL.getWebGLErrorMessage());
        }

        // Editable
        var divWidth = 300;
        var divHeight = 300;
        var modelId = 'modelGrid';
        var modelClass = 'col-sm';

        // Don't change
        var modelContainer;
        var camera, cameraTarget, scene, renderer;
        var cameraFov = 45;


        init(data);
        animate();


        // init
        function init(data) {

            // For loop for every model in the json file
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                var filename = data[i].Filename;

                // Scene
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffe5e5);

                // Camera
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(cameraFov, divWidth / divHeight, 1, 15);
                cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3(0, -0.25, 0);

                // Creates a div with the name of the value of var className, inside modelGrid id
                modelContainer = document.createElement('div');
                modelContainer.className = modelClass; // Add class to the div
                document.getElementById(modelId).appendChild(modelContainer);

                // STL Loader
                var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
                loader.load('model/' + filename, function(geometry) {
                    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
                        color: 0xff1919,
                        roughness: 0.5,
                        metalness: 0
                    });
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                    mesh.position.set(0, -0.5, 0); // Position with the Y value
                    mesh.rotation.set(0, -Math.PI / 2, 0);
                    mesh.scale.set(0.15, 0.15, 0.15);
                    scene.add(mesh); // add model to the scene
                });

                // Lights
                scene.add(new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xaaaaaa, 0x444444));
                var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
                light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
                scene.add(light);

                // renderer
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                    antialias: true
                });
                renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
                renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
                renderer.setSize(divWidth, divHeight);
                // renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                renderer.gammaInput = true;
                renderer.gammaOutput = true;
                renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
                modelContainer.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
                // window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
            }
        }

        // animate
        function animate() {
            render();
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }

        // render
        function render() {
            renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
            var timer = Date.now() * 0.0005;
            camera.position.x = Math.cos(timer) * 3;
            camera.position.z = Math.sin(timer) * 3;
            camera.lookAt(cameraTarget);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're only saving and rendering a single three.js renderer. In your for loop this line is overwriting the global `renderer` variable, which is referenced in your `render()` function:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
});
```

There are a few ways to fix this including adding the renderers and cameras into an array and iterating over them in a single render function or creating a new `animate()` loop for each renderer, etc. Here's a rough example of the second option:

```
// For loop for every model in the json file
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    var filename = data[i].Filename;

    // EDIT Fix3: These variables must be defined inside of the for loop 
    // scope otherwise they will be shared by all loop iterations
    var modelContainer;
    var camera, cameraTarget, scene;

    // ...

    // Fix 1: Add var declaration so the variable is scoped to this
    // block and variables are not defined globally and overwritten on
    // subsequent iterations. This is needed for all the variables
    // in this block (scene, camera, etc)
    // renderer
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true
    });

    // ...

    // Fix 2: Create an animation loop for each renderer instead
    // of a single global one
    // animate
    function animate() {
        render();
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    // render
    function render() {
        renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
        var timer = Date.now() * 0.0005;
        camera.position.x = Math.cos(timer) * 3;
        camera.position.z = Math.sin(timer) * 3;
        camera.lookAt(cameraTarget);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    animate();    

}
```

There are definitely cleaner approaches to this but hopefully this gets you started! Let me know if that works out or you need clarification.

edit: I just noticed that your image shows all three models displayed on top of each other. This is again because the `scene` variable is declared globally and by the time the asynchronous `load` function is fired it is set to the final scene object.

Comment: Hey man thanks for your input!

I understand what you mean and tried to apply it on my code. It did went a step in the right direction because now the two left boxes are rendered pink now. So this means that the scene is rendered if I'm correct.

Ps. I'm trying to send the update code with my comment but it doesn't work. I know that I have to place my code between ``, but it says that I used too much characters..

Comment: So I got rid of the global variables,
at the end of the for loop I called the animate function,
and I placed the animate() and render() function inside the init() function.

So all divs have the scene background:

`scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffe5e5);`
But all 3 models are still rendered in the last div, stacked on each other like you can see in the image in my description

Comment: Glad progress was made -- I just updated my post with "Fix 3" so make sure to take a look. You've gotten rid of the global variables but the scene variable is still outside of the for loop scope which means it still gets overwritten during each iteration of the loop and you'll get the same issues you had with global variables. Moving them inside the for loop scope should fix this.

Comment: Hey Garrett I can't see your Fix 3 and the scene var was made inside the for loop.

I tried to analyse this code since it represents closely to what I want to achieve but I couldn't successfully implement it yet.
https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_elements

In the example they push the scene into scenes within the for loop `scenes.push(scene);`

Then they use a foreach in the render() function, within that foreach they do the `renderer.render(scene, camera);`

Also I noticed that the renderer is outside the for loop but inside the init() function.

Comment: That example is much more complex and aims to get around the limitation of 16 webgl contexts on a page while using a single renderer. I would understand your current problem a bit more before moving on to something like that if you need it. The update is labeled `EDIT Fix3:` in a comment inside of the code block and moves all variable declarations (`modelContainer`, `scene`, `camera`, `cameraTarget`, `renderer`)inside of the for loop. While the scene etc is *instantiated* inside of the loop the variables are declared outside the scope meaning they will get overwritten.

Comment: I also see that you mentioned that you moved the `render` and `animate` functions inside of the `init` function. It's important that they be moved inside of the for loop along with those variables as I've shown in my example.

Comment: It's fixed now! :)

I swapped the for loop with a foreach hehe ... This did the trick!

Thanks for all your help

Comment: Great! You mean a forEach loop fixed the problem? Or you moved the functions and variables into the loop, as well?

Comment: You can check the new code here (the code needs cleaning I know haha) https://codepen.io/indoguy/project/editor/XqNKGQ

So inside the init() is a foreach. In the foreach is the scene, camera, "div creator", model loader, lights and renderer.

Comment: Great -- glad to see it worked! If it's fixed you should consider marking my answer as a solution or posting a different answer with how you fixed it.